# Tableau Calculation to show previous week data when Report Wk is selected in the filter

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I have a dashboard on the tableau desktop 2019.2.4 version where I am highlighting couple metrics as shown in the screenshot.
[image]
The Grouping filter has 5 values as ALL, CONS, CONS Inbound, CONS Outbound, and IMPORT.

Report week filter has week numbers. say for example the previous completed week is the 7th week of 2020 then the Report week filter will show values as 12005,12006, Report Wk and the previous weeks.

Report wk filter is working of off column- WM_YR_WK_ID2 from the attached sheet.

Let's assume I select Grouping filter as ALL

In the Service section for the highlighted metrics I want to show previous week values if Report wk is selected.

If Report Week Filter= "Report Wk"(In this example 7th week) then show values for week 6th in the service section

If Report Week Filter= "12006" then show values for week 6th in the service section

If Report Week Filter= "12005" then show values for week 5th in the service section

The service section is always going to be one week in arrears.
In the attached sample workbook, I want to show "LOS OT %-Weekly" as 78.3% when I select WM_YR_WK_ID2 as "Report Wk"

I tried using LAST(),FIRST(),RANK() etc functions but unable to get it right.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I want to attach an excel file and a Tableau workbook here for better understanding of the question, how can I do that? I don't see an option.

Comment: One way is to publish it to http://public.tableau.com and then post a URL. You can also post your question to Tableau's forum on their website.